# AWS Cognito: Use as central authentication system for different apps in the company

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to use AWS Cognito for my company where we have different applications with both in-house and client access. The following are few of the requirements:

- List all users in the console (view email, last-login etc)
- Limit access to users of specific domains
- Assign roles and permissions to different users
- Assign roles in console or via. API
- Issue access tokens containing username/roles/permissions
- Decode access token in the app and to allow/deny access based on roles
- Send email notifications for the current user from within the app

I was assuming that AWS Cognito was a general purpose authentication/authorization solution, with APIs that could be tailored to any auth needs. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Do you have a question?

Answer (score 0):

Cognito covers a lot of what you described in your use case description and sounds like it might suit your use case. However without a concise question, it's very hard to give a good quality answer.

I suggest you check out the Cognito Docs, and then come back with any clarifying questions that you have. 
https://aws.amazon.com/cognito